# positioning images in css with interactivity

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to create an interactive chart with circles around a main circle...
Live example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YORZdX

```css
.gbt-container {}

.asset-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 11.7%;
  margin-top: -5.85%;
  margin-left: -5.85%;
}

.im--0 {}

.im--1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(35%, -120%);
  -ms-transform: translate(35%, -120%);
  transform: translate(35%, -120%);
}

.im--2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(125%, -69%);
  -ms-transform: translate(125%, -69%);
  transform: translate(125%, -69%);
}

.im--3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(165%, 65%);
  -ms-transform: translate(165%, 65%);
  transform: translate(165%, 65%);
}

.im--4 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(124%, 195%);
  -ms-transform: translate(124%, 195%);
  transform: translate(124%, 195%);
}

.im--5 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(40%, 240%);
  -ms-transform: translate(40%, 240%);
  transform: translate(40%, 240%);
}

.im--6 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 195%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 195%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 195%);
}

.im--7 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 60%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-90%, 60%);
  transform: translate(-90%, 60%);
}

.im--8 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-52%, -70%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-52%, -70%);
  transform: translate(-52%, -70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gbt-container">
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--0">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cdgHCK/L1.png" alt="L1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--1">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--2">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--3">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--4">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--5">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--6">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--7">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--8">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems to work fine on desktop, I might still need to work on positioning everything equally but it breaks in mobile. Does anyone know what I'm missing to make this responsive?

Thanks!

Comment: You first need to decide how you want your responsive design to fuction. Do you want the items to resize or relocate?

Comment: Would it not be best for the images to resize based on screen dimensions?

Comment: ok give me a few mins, i'll see what I can knock up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to rebuild your design a little but this should now be responsive.

```css
.gbt-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.asset-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.asset-wrapper img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.im--0 {
  margin: 50% 0 0 50%;
}

.im--2 {
  margin: 50% 50% 0 0;
}

.im--6 {
  margin: 0 0 50% 50%;
}

.im--8 {
  margin: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gbt-container">
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--0">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="L1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--1">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--2">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--3">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--4">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cdgHCK/L1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--5">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--6">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--7">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
  <div class="asset-wrapper im--8">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jvu16e/S1.png" alt="S1" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that uses percentages to get a desired look across different platforms, and here is a codepen => https://codepen.io/kipomaha/pen/bxQRqy/

--- Edit ---

It is important to remember that when you use snippets like this to keep in mind the type of positioning you use when you insert this into your HTML page. For a multi image display container like the one below in the example, you must keep in mind where most of your customers will most likely be when they look up your site.

This will help you plan how you want your pages and the pages children elements to be displayed in relation to one another. To set this you can set an elements `display` attribute. In css3 the common approach would be to use grid or flex layout which are both well documented and can be used across most modern devices uniformly.

Flex or grid layouts are good for menus and other box style elements and more information can be found on mdn.com or w3s.com.

```
.gbt-container {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div.gbt-container > a > div > img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}
.asset-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 11.7%;
  margin-top: -5.85%;
  margin-left: -5.85%;
}

.im--0 {  
  -webkit-transform: translate(35%, 60%);
  -ms-transform: translate(35%, 60%);
  transform: translate(35%, 60%);
}

.im--1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(35%, -120%);
  -ms-transform: translate(35%, -120%);
  transform: translate(35%, -120%);
}

.im--2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(125%, -69%);
  -ms-transform: translate(125%, -69%);
  transform: translate(125%, -69%);
}

.im--3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(165%, 65%);
  -ms-transform: translate(165%, 65%);
  transform: translate(165%, 65%);
}

.im--4 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(124%, 195%);
  -ms-transform: translate(124%, 195%);
  transform: translate(124%, 195%);
}

.im--5 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(40%, 240%);
  -ms-transform: translate(40%, 240%);
  transform: translate(40%, 240%);
}

.im--6 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 195%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 195%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 195%);
}

.im--7 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 60%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-90%, 60%);
  transform: translate(-90%, 60%);
}

.im--8 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-52%, -70%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-52%, -70%);
  transform: translate(-52%, -70%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, this seems to work well. When wrapping the images with an anchor tag, it messes up the code. I thought that text-decoration: none would help but doesn't seem to make any changes.

Comment: Make sure you re-target css selectors.

Comment: When adding this to a page filled content it overlaps. I actually found a perfect example of what I'm looking to do here: https://www.ems-dental.com/en/guided-biofilm-therapy

Comment: What overlaps the circles or the parent div that holds them?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b294e792b273930448daba5e482d07da

Take a look at the screenshot. I'm throwing this on a Drupal page.

Comment: The div that contains the image is being styled using the `position: fixed;` or the `position: absolute;`  property.  Try setting the .gbt-container class to relative, or the element that holds the text to relative or both of them.